# Syncronize timestamp between devices

Tags: java, timestamp, lan

I'm looking into syncronizing some devices, and I am having a local solution requiring to work without internet.

I have used the System.currentTimeMillis(); but it's good only for one device as system clocks arent totally sync even with automatic time update and same timezones. So I was wondering, what can I use as I cannot use NTP server/internet?

Is the fastest way to get it by setting up a server on a pc, connect via cable to the router and query it for it's timestamp?
Or use a android device as a server and query that?

Is there any other solution? open to everything within java/c++ and wlan/wifi (no internet)

---

Update,

Have been searching for some hours.. And found that many(almost everyone) have the same issue without NTP. Giving it more thought, I will just create that server solution on a lan connection and fetch a timestamp.. Still open for ideas though :)

Answer (score 0):

you can implement all sort of solutions with distributed memory, but it's exhausting, and you'll be introduced with many different issues... 
synchronizing all servers with NTP servers is the way to go.